# declaring reference as auto in c++

Tags: c++, reference, auto

I'm not sure how the *auto* keyword works. Here is an illustration of my issue:

```
class Element {
  public:
    void setA(int a) {
      m_a = a;
    }

    int& a() {
      return m_a;
    }

  private:
    int m_a = 0;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Element el;

  auto a = el.a();
  a = 2;
  // displays 2, 0
  std::cout << a << ", " << el.a() << std::endl;

  int& b = el.a();
  b = 3;
  // displays 3, 3
  std::cout << b << ", " << el.a() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In my understanding, *auto* deduce the declaration type from the context in which it is used. Here, it should deduce the *a* variable as being a reference to an integer since Element:a() is declared as a method returning a reference to an integer.

Instead, it seems that the *a* variable is a copy of the m_a attribute of the Element class.

I found that I needed to specify *auto&* to get a reference to the attribute. But I don't really understand why I need to add the ampersand. Shouldn't the compiler know that if *a* is initialized from a method returning a reference, then it should also be a reference ?

Comment: You need to use `auto&` for a reference.

Comment: If the rule was like you suggested, then how would you make a *copy* of the reference returned by `a`?

Comment: If you want a reference, you need to add the `&`.  Otherwise you are making a copy into a new object.  (If the syntax was reversed, and `auto` would make a reference to a returned reference, what would be the syntax of `auto` to not make a reference?  Maybe `auto!&`?

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't the compiler know that if a is initialized from a method returning a reference, then it should also be a reference ?

It could, but that's not how C++ works.

The expression `el.a()` is an *lvalue* `int`, not a reference. The expression refers to the original object, but the reference qualifier has been dropped by this point. It's complicated and confusing but that's just how C++ works. Consequently, it's also how `auto` works.

You'll have to write `auto&` to get a new reference. A bonus of this is that there is syntax to get a copy, which there wouldn't be otherwise.

It's the same as why the expression `std::move(aThing)` is an rvalue of type `T`, not of type `T&&`, even though `std::move` is literally a cast to `T&&`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have any link to some resource where I could learn more about it ? I didn't really knew what to search for when working on this by myself.

Comment: @NicolasAppriou Sorry, I don't know which (if any) books go into this level of detail. The "why" of C++ is quite involved. Perhaps somebody else has a suggestion though.